# How to expire cart after a limited time

Tags: java, php, timer, shopping-cart, cart

I need Help on how to expire a shopping cart
Suppose we have a shopping cart in a e-commerce website, and a user adds a product to his shopping cart the problem is that from the inventory we should decrement the quantity of that product because it’s being held by a user. 
The idea is we implement a timer in the shopping cart when that timer expires, the user doesn’t hold that product anymore.

My questions are :

- How to implement a timer that will work across all pages in the website
- How to trigger the event of updating the inventory once the timer is done.

Hope my explanation was clear.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Im using cron job for releasing quantity back to the product. you can use a timer using javascript to trigger api call to the backend to release. However, when user close the broswer, API call will not be triggered. So, you will still need to fall back to a cron job or a job scheduler to call the API.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *How to implement a timer that will work across all pages in the website*? That it works with every customer that has an open cart or that you notify everyone that the product is available again? As for the other question Kimberlee was faster and already answered it. The safes is to use some kind of scheduler to run periodically and start your "cleanup" (cron for linux or task scheduler for windows).

Comment: @ViliamAboši when i said that the timer should work across all pages i meant that for exemple when i'm on the homepage (not the cart page) the timer is still decremeting even though i'm not in the cart page

Comment: My solution will do that, but you have to start session and check timer on the pages you want to use it on.

Answer (score 1):

One example using session, don't forget that the session will expire when the browser is closed. If you want more persistant data storage, use cookies or localStorage.

```
<?php

/* Constants */
define('EXPIRATION_TIME', 30); // minutes

/* Dummy variables */
$productAdded = true;

/* Start session */
session_start();

/* Check timer */
if (isset($_SESSION['timer']) && $_SESSION['timer'] < time()) {

    /* 
        30 min have gone by and the user has not added more products
        to the cart, lets empty the cart and reset the timer
    */

    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
    unset($_SESSION['timer']);
}

/* Add product */
if ($productAdded) {

    /* Increase timer */
    $_SESSION['timer'] = (time() + (EXPIRATION_TIME * 60));

    /* Add product to cart, and all other tasks */
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
        $_SESSION['cart'] = array();

    $_SESSION['cart'][] = array(
        'id' => 17,
        'name' => 'Fancy shampoo',
        'quantity' => 1337
    );
}

?>
```

Comment: thank you very much, it seems like it will work , i'll try it and give feedback